# How do I use Cache mechanism for returned database events

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, ojdbc, jcs

My database(Oracle) pushes rowID's when DML operations are performed and my java program has a listeners which handles the events and gets the rowID's.

For Example: Below are the values returned from database on DML operation

ROW:  operation=UPDATE, ROWID=AAASjgAABAAAVapAAA

Now I have to store this rowID's in a cache? How do I do this in java? Any clues would help.
I am thinking of JCS or Ehcache. Which one is preferrable?

**Handling RowID's returned as part of DB events through a listener:**

```
class DCNDemoListener implements DatabaseChangeListener
    {
      DBChangeNotification demo;
      DCNDemoListener(DBChangeNotification dem)
      {
        demo = dem;
      }
      public void  onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
      }
    }
```

Comment: how exactly will you deal with your cache? do you need multiple machines accessing this cache or you just need it for your current program, so a simple HashSet would do the job? What about cache expiration feature, do you need it? do you need to store the rowid only or other data as well?

Comment: Yes multiple machines will be accessing the cache. I need to store only the rowId's

Comment: You need to build a clustered cache. How do you plan to get notified when updates & deletes are performed?

Comment: Updated the question please have a look. I am already handling the notifications. All I need is to store this returned RowId's and update another table in database. But how do I do this? :(

Comment: Can you define the problem statement clearly so that a solution could be thought off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [basic caching documentation for Ehcache 2.9.0](http://ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-codebasics_basic_caching.html%23wwconnect_header).

Regarding recommendations on technology, hard to say given only limited information about the use case is presented.